# Javascript function do an data-action on a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i´ve got the following code in my website:

```
<a class="jr-btn jr-btn-success " data-action="sendStep"> Senden </a>
```

I want to do the data-action called by a javascript-function. Is it possible?

Comment: yes use attribute selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and you would use the `.getAttribute('data-action')` to get the value

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("jr-btn-success")[0].getAttribute('data-action'))
```

```html
<a class="jr-btn jr-btn-success " data-action="sendStep"> Senden </a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! But how do i start the action "sendStep"?

Comment: @AlexanderMenger What do you mean by starting the action?